# Is it possible to quiesce ms-access for a database backup using VSS?

Tags: windows-server-2003, backup, vss, quiesce

I was on the phone today with a remote site backup provider and they talked about using Volume Shadowing Service to make a fast database-aware backup.  They said that in order for this to work, it would help to have a database that was backup aware, that the backup could [Quiesce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiesce) so that no new transactions would be allowed during the backup, but all in progress transactions would either be written to the log until the backup was complete, or be allowed to complete.

Does MS-Access support this?  If so which versions?

Comment: Microsoft has come out and said that Access isn't recommended in really any situation, so if, possible, move that data into something resembling a real database, rather than an overgrown spreadsheet MS won't give you support on.

Comment: A database application with VSS support would be something like MS SQL that runs on the server the database is hosted on. This allows for connections to the database via it's own set of protocols, not simply a microsoft access database file stored on a file share. When the backup application wants to back up the database it will effectively inform MS SQL of the intended backup, at which point the database application would finish writing and "freeze" the database in a usable state prior to backup. Without an intelligent hosting application such as this VSS is not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't. If you get a VSS snap of it, you'll get it as it is at the time of the snap.